# Error 1815 when backup up SQL08 DB

Tags: sql-server, backup

I’m trying to backup a SQL08 database to a target on a remote drive and keep ending up with error reason “1815”. This happens either when scripting the backup or using the task wizard GUI. It also occurs when attempting to use either UNC or a shared drive letter to the same path. Another machine on the network doesn’t have a problem backing up to the same path. The network location has write access open to all. Any ideas?

BTW, the successful machine is a server 2008 VPC running on Vista while the one failing is just running directly on an XP host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the write access to the UNC for the service account that sql server runs under.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've an existing backup rename it and execute again